# Run a build several times in the same chain in Teamcity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, git-flow

I have a bulid configuration *A* for merging feature branches in my project, which runs configuration *B* for several different modes (dev and prod). *B* compiles the project and runs tests. The mode is passed via a bulid parameter.

I've set it up this way:

1. *A* depends on *B-dev* and *B-prod*
2. *B-dev* depends on *B*, passing a dev mode parameter, and has no steps
3. *B-prod* depends on *B*, passing a prod mode parameter, and has no steps

I want to run *B* two times in the same chain, but looks like Teamcity doesn't allow that. Is there any way other than duplicating the *B* configuration?

Comment: use `Dependencies - rebuild all` when you want to run

Comment: `Do not run new build if there is a suitable one` means to rebuild every time

Comment: there currently is no build matrix support in teamcity. there is a plugin that goes into that direction (dont know if it is still maintained). And if you are looking for a way to not duplicate the build (I think it would be the cleanest way, extract it into a template and use that one parameter) you could use the rest api and a curl script to trigger the build twice with different settings (but this will look weird in the build chain)

Answer (score 0):

When configuring your snapshot dependency from `B-*` to `B`, uncheck the flag "*Do not run new build if there is a suitable one*":

[image]

According to the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2019.1/snapshot-dependencies.html):

> If the option is enabled, TeamCity will not run a dependency build, if another running or finished dependency build with the appropriate sources revision exists.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. Gives the same results

Comment: @A.K.does every build configuration, that depends on B, have this checkbox off?

Comment: yep. Looks like there's just no way to do that in Teamcity, as wemu pointed out